# Does having highly correlated independent variables undermine the determination of whether they can significantly predict the dependent variable?

Tags: multiple-regression

I'm doing a multiple linear regression model in R to test whether sales price, sales, and cost of sales can significantly predict profit. Results showed that R-squared = 1 which indicates that 100% of the variance in profit is explainable by my predictors. I also tested the correlation between my independent variables and they are all strongly correlated. In this case, can I conclude that my IVs can significantly predict my DV (profit)? And how do I report (in APA style) the collinearity in my IVs?

Comment: I guess your model is overfit. I would be very weary interpreting it at all.

Comment: I’m pretty skeptical about $R^2=1$. Is that out-of-sample, with MSE and MAE equal to zero?

Comment: Of course you get 100% of profit explained as the profit is a linear combination of your independent variables. You don't need a regression to figure that out. It's `profit = sales*price - sales*cost`. So, you get regression coefficients of `1.0` and `-1.0` for the interaction terms and no other effects. This is not what you use regression for.

Comment: We need some more information! Please give us sample size at least, and show us some regression output and plots.